# Is there like "firstIndexOf" code?

Tags: string, indexof

```
String xStr = "hello/master/yoda";
String remv_last = xStr.substring(0, xStr.lastIndexOf("/"))
System.out.println(remv_last);
```

output

```
hello/master
```

My question is; how can I get this output, thanks for helping.

```
master/yoda
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use indexOf

```
String xStr = "hello/master/yoda";
String remv_last = xStr.substring(xStr.indexOf("/") + 1);
 System.out.println(remv_last);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple indexOf it will give you the first occurrence only

```
        String xStr = "hello/master/yoda";
    String remv_last = xStr.substring(0, xStr.lastIndexOf("/"));
    int firstIndex = xStr.indexOf("/");
    String firstCharacter = xStr.substring(firstIndex,xStr.length());
    System.out.println(remv_last);
    System.out.println(firstCharacter);
```

It will print required